# Are there any taunts that can be used as an attack?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In SSB4, I heard there was a taunt that could hit, which ended up being Luigi's down taunt, I think. I do not play this game really often, so I was wondering, are there any other taunt attacks? I have seen some that look like they should be attacks, but I haven't quite tested them out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SSB4, there are two characters with damaging taunts:

- Luigi's down taunt (the heel scuff) is a meteor smash of fixed knockback. Using on an unsuspecting opponent that's near or on an edge can result in a satisfying KO.

[image: Luigi down taunt]

- Greninja's down taunt (the palm fountains) is a multi-hit attack that does 0.5% damage per hit. It's slow and weak, and can't even KO in Sudden Death, but it's damaging.

[image: Greninja down taunt]

Comment: In Brawl, Snake's box taunt could also be used to damage enemies